# Mouse/Touchpad acceleration disabling not working

Tags: xorg, mouse, elementary-os, touchpad

I'm running elementary OS, I installed it on my laptop to try it out but I can't disable the pointer acceleration (I'm only using the touchpad). I tried adding a bash script to startup to run `xset m 0 0` but it only works for around 1 second after login. I also tried creating a file `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/90-mouse-accel-disable.conf` with the following code:

```
Section "InputClass"
  Identifier "mouse"
  MatchIsPointer "on"
  Option "AccelerationProfile" "-1"
  Option "AccelerationScheme" "none"
EndSection
```

but it doesn't work either.

xinput devices:

```
$ xinput --list
 Virtual core pointer                       id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                 id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
   ↳ ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad                   id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
 Virtual core keyboard                      id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ WebCam SC-13HDL12131N                     id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Is there another solution to this? Any advice is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Try the following filter instead:

`MatchIsTouchpad "on"`